# How to offer google translation when page is in same language as browser lang

Tags: google-translate

I want to be able to offer translation to other languages when the browser language is the same as the default lang in google translate.

I am using the translate widget from google and if the language matches the widget, it is not being shown, if not i works as it is supposed to, how can i force it to appear?